# SQL Server day datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

I am creating a table for an application that handles scheduling and deals with recurring events.  I need to indicate which days and times an event may recur on (eg. every Monday and Wednesday at 1pm).  Is there a datatype that can handle only days of the week without inputting specific dates, or will I need to create another table containing days of the week and reference these with a FK?  This is obviously undesirable because it will make handling events that start before midnight and end after midnight more complex.

Comment: `TINYINT` - since the *numerical* day can only have values from 1 to 7 (or 0 to 6) - there's really no need to use anything more than a `TINYINT` which can have values up to 255 (1 byte storage)

Comment: Use tinyinteger/byte, from either 0 to 6 or 1 to 7.

Comment: You can use a `smallint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a smallint for the Day of Week.

If you are using SQL Server 2008, there is a new [**time**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) datatype for the time of day column, otherwise you will still need to use a datetime datatype.

Comment: One thing I'd add is to create a `CHECK` constraint on the column requiring the value to be between 1 and 7 (or 0 and 6, depending on the implementation).  Also... why smallint and not tinyint?

Comment: @Aaronaught: Interestingly, years later, another developer will come and think the days of the week starts at Monday and write code to that effect (and probably by-pass enums you have in the code.) Another will think it starts on Sunday. There are probably some that will not know why you have numbers rather than characters for day of the week. I recommend creating a another table that maps a number to a day of the week; and referencing that table for days of the week. It extra work and probably over-kill, but can save the future team from nasty production bugs in the far future.

Comment: @Phil: A character column would not be a good idea if you ever plan to support multiple languages. But yes, I always create enum tables in the database addition to enum types in the code; they are of course never aware of each other but at least it's there as a reference for future devs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    DAY_OF_WEEK TINYINT CHECK (DAY_OF_WEEK BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
    -- Other fields and constraints...
)
```